# How to deploy Azure function using Java programatically?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-aks, azure-service-principal

I am new to Azure cloud so have couple of questions related to Azure cloud and its services. First of all, let me give you a brief about the feature I am working on and why azure is needed there.

Problem statement: I am building a micro service, in Java spring-boot, where I am supposed to create an Azure function. In the Azure function, I need to execute one ".jar" file. ".jar" is having the code that is going to perform some tasks on private Kubernetes cluster, hence my Azure function is going to receive a input request about Kubernetes cluster, the Azure vnet details (using Azure Virtual Network to secure the kubernetes cluster). The ".jar" file is going to be deployed on the blob storage service of Azure. The Azure function is supposed to read the ".jar" file and execute it.

Everything mentioned above needs to be done programmatically, with Azure SDK APIs.

I hope the problem statement is clear. Now, everything needs to be done programmatically. And for that I need to explore the Azure SDK but I didn't find a good documentation regarding the same.

As of now, the solutions I have came across are Azure portal, Azure cli and Azure toolkit plugin (I used "Azure toolkit for IntelliJ" to create an azure function for some POC). But as I am building a micro service, I want everything programmatically and was exploring Azure SDK for Java but didn't find the APIs.

If anyone is aware about the APIs please share the related docs.
Thanks!

Comment: You want the azure function code in `Java` to run your .jar file? you want execution automatically or when you trigger it manually?

Comment: Hey @VivekVaibhavShandilya, thanks for the reply. I want to create an azure function programatically. No use of azure portal, azure cli or Azure toolkit for IntelliJ. I should be able to create it with azure sdk apis which I can directly call in my java code.

Comment: so you wanna create azure function on the fly from code ?

Comment: Yes @Thomas. Like for Azure blob storage, we have a client library written in Java. I can use that to create a blob client, container, and eventually store the data(or blob) inside the container. I am looking for something similar for azure functions.

Comment: Have you check the azure sdk for java? https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, AFAIK Currently it is not possible to execute the file.

I was able to create an Azure function app and deployed the Jar file in the function from the storage account.

But unfortunately, it not possible to execute the file programmatically.

My code to create function app and get the file content form the storage account.

To Run jar file, I have created `hello_jar.zip` file and I had my `hello_jar.jar` file in that.

for reference check [Azure Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk)

**`functionapp.java`:**

```java
import com.azure.resourcemanager.appservice.AppServiceManager;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.appservice.models.FunctionApp;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.appservice.models.JavaVersion;
import com.azure.storage.blob.*;
import com.azure.storage.blob.sas.BlobSasPermission;
import com.azure.storage.blob.sas.BlobServiceSasSignatureValues;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential;
import com.azure.core.management.AzureEnvironment;
import com.azure.core.management.profile.AzureProfile;
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder;


public class functionapp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        String resourceGroupName = "Vivek-JavaFunc";

        String functionAppName = "javasdkfuncapp";

        String tenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        String conn ="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=jarfilestorage;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";


        // Create DefaultAzureCredential using the default settings (e.g., managed identity, environment variables, etc.)
        TokenCredential credential= new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder()
            .build();

        AzureProfile profile = new AzureProfile(tenantId, subscriptionId, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
        
        // Initialize the Azure AppServiceManager
        AppServiceManager manager = AppServiceManager
            .configure()
            .authenticate(credential,profile);

        BlobServiceClient blobclient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(conn).buildClient();
        
        BlobContainerClient container = blobclient.getBlobContainerClient("test");

        BlobClient file= container.getBlobClient("hello_jar.zip");

        BlobServiceSasSignatureValues SAS= new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(
            OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(1), 
            BlobSasPermission.parse("racwd")
        );

        // Define the Function App
        FunctionApp functionApp  =  manager
                .functionApps()
                .define(functionAppName)
                .withRegion("East US") // Set your desired Azure region
                .withNewResourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
                .withNewConsumptionPlan()
                .withLatestRuntimeVersion()
                .withRuntime("java")
                .withJavaVersion(JavaVersion.JAVA_11)
                .withWebContainer(null)
                .create();


        System.out.println("Azure Function App created with name: " + functionApp.name());


        String SAStoken = file.generateSas(SAS);

        String SASurl = file.getBlobUrl()+"?"+SAStoken;


        functionApp.update()
            .withAppSetting("WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE", SASurl)
            .apply();
    
        System.out.println("Setting has been updated in function: " + functionApp.name());

    }

}
```

**`pom.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <azure.sdk.version>1.10.1</azure.sdk.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core-management</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.43.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.resourcemanager</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-resourcemanager-appservice</artifactId>
            <version>2.30.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.resourcemanager</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-resourcemanager</artifactId>
            <version>2.30.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
            <version>12.24.0</version>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>functionapp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My `.jar` file directory

```
hello_jar.zip/
    hello_jar.jar
```

**`Output`:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Executed manually.

[image]